# Is there any way of emulating a Apple SMC chip in intel Based UEFI?

Tags: boot, uefi

**Is there any way of emulating a Apple SMC chip in intel Based PC UEFI?**

The System Management Controller (SMC) is a subsystem of Intel processor-based Macintosh computers.

@sun2sirius

Comment: @sun2sirius I look forward to hear your answar, it will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous [FakeSMC.kext](https://github.com/RehabMan/OS-X-FakeSMC-kozlek/tree/master/FakeSMC) driver that performs partial emulation of SMC. It can be ported to UEFI with enough effort.

Comment: Fakesmc kext require bootloader and Mac OS system to emulate smc, is there a way to emulate a smc in hardware level? Which will be present as virtual address?

Comment: To boot a hackintosh we must have a fakesmc kext, which requires kext injection in bootloader, sometime we should put the kext in S/L/E or L/E then rebuilding the kernelcache. So if we could let the UEFI emulate virtual SMC , then no need for the kext at all. There is ozmosis which we could put fakesmc in the uefi as ffs but this make no sense, as it will work as kext in efi partition which requires also bootloader(OZ) to emulate. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Could we ? Emulate it as you said in uefi? But in hardware level as real Mac?